# Vue + jest debug

Tags: vue.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, jestjs

i'm trying to debug in vs code my vue project which uses jest for testing.

**jest.config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'jsx',
    'json',
    'vue'
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.vue$': 'vue-jest',
    '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$': 'jest-transform-stub',
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest'
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/',
    '/node_modules/(?!@babel)'
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1'
  },
  snapshotSerializers: [
    'jest-serializer-vue'
  ],
  testMatch: [
    '**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__tests__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'
  ],
  testURL: 'http://localhost/',
  watchPlugins: [
    'jest-watch-typeahead/filename',
    'jest-watch-typeahead/testname'
  ]
}
```

**launch.json** :

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
 {
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Debug Unit Tests",
    "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
    "runtimeArgs": [
      "run-script",
      "test:debug",
      "${file}"
    ],
    "port": 9229
  }
]
```

}

I've tried almost every tutorial online like : 
https://medium.com/@sarngru/debug-vuejs-jest-tests-in-vscode-63e2ed45e503
when tried to run debugging got :

```
node_modules\.bin\vue-cli-service:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:267:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:319:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:684:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:12)
    at executeUserCode (internal/bootstrap/node.js:342:17)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

tried npm install -g @vue/cli-service-global but it doesnt work as well.. plese help! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me
launch.json :

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Jest",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
      "args": ["-i"],
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**/*.js", "node_modules"]
    } 
   ]
}
```